# ARM system booting from SD card with uboot - how to put everything in one FAT partition?

Tags: kernel, embedded, root-filesystem, u-boot, buildroot

I am working on an ARM system running linux, which has an eMMC and an SD card slot. I've been booting from the SD card during development, with just the first stage bootloader of uboot in the eMMC and the second stage loader on the SD card. The SD card was partitioned by uboot originally. [image: partition layout sd card]

I am now preparing to deploy this to the field and would like to just use the SD card for everything and not use the eMMC (we will remove the eMMC to avoid the possibility of bricking the system).

I want the FAT partitions on the sd card to be accessible on mac and windows since the user will have to copy files from/to the card. On mac osx, the fat partitions show up. On windows, they don't ...

Right now I'm not using buildroot yet or a similar tool to build the kernel, rootfs and application.

Is there a way to put one big FAT partition on the SD card, being the boot partition, which would have the kernel and device tree blob on it, as well as the rootfs and application? If there is just one big FAT partition this would avoid that the user can mess up the SD card or accidentally reformat it when inserted into a windows PC. Since u-boot is written to the SD card at specific locations it wouldn't be visible to the end user.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Suggestion:  Windows USB will only 'see' the first partition, SD might be the same. IF your first partition was the FAT one and your second was say FAT or ext type and on the second you could put the device tree and kernel. Stuff you do not want a windows user to change. BTW: you rootFS could be on the large FAT partition.

Comment: also a third partition could be the swap if you need one.